# PhpStorm - HTML 5 boilerplate code snippet

Tags: html, templates, phpstorm

I am an avid user of Visual Studio Code and before that Sublime Text. I have recently started using PhpStorm for my Laravel projects and I am really missing the ability to instantly produce a simple HTML 5 boilerplate template by simply typing `html` + `TAB`.

Is there anything similar in PhpStorm?

Comment: `File > New Project > HTML5 Boilerplate` or `Create New Project > HTML5 Boilerplate`

Answer (score 72, accepted):

> Is there anything similar in PhpStorm?

`!` + <kbd>Tab</kbd> IIRC.

In IDEA-based IDEs it's called [Live Templates](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm). IDE also supports [Emmet](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.1/emmet.html?search=emmet).

All **Live Templates** can be found at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Live Templates` -- you can modify exiting or add your own (I suggest using own groups for own templates -- less possible hassle with updates and sharing).

Snippets for HTML (plus standard Emmet abbreviations) are located under `Zen HTML` node.

You can also customise the expand key:

- by default it's offered among usual <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> .. but you can also configure your own shortcut.
- each Live Template can be set to use different expand key (among those mentioned above) .. although I do not really see any real benefit for this.

---

You can also use **File Templates** ([[ 1 ]](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.1/file-and-code-templates.html) and [[ 2 ]](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/File+Templates+in+PhpStorm)) to make files with some predefined content/structure.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Great answer!

Comment: Thanks a lot; that is very helpful